# Catalog Price Rules Dates Not Working

Tags: catalog, price, rules

I'm using magento 1.9.0.1

When I make a catalog price rule  to run a specific set of dates it doesn't work properly.  If it is the only rule it will work.  However, if there is another rule that is active and is currently running it will activate the first rules discount.

Comment: Check if Promotions > Catalog Price Rules > Actions > Stop Further Rules Processing is set to "No".

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail.

Comment: It was a bug, and fixed in magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed in magento 1.9.1.0.   You must upgrade from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1.0 in order to receive the fix.